# Seeding is not working with EF 4.1

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following code I created with help of asp.net mvc tutorials.
These are in a different class library I called Model.
I created an app.config in the class library with the connection string called HRContext.
Also on the webproject I created the same connection string.

When I run the project, I put breakpoints and the Seed method is never executed, however the OnModelCreating is being executed.

I got an exception saying that the table dbo.Position does not exist in the view.

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Position'.



Line 21:             var positions = unitOfWork.PositionRepository.Find(p => p.PositionID != null);
Line 22: 
Line 23:             return View(positions.ToList());
Line 24:         }








 public class HRContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<HRContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(HRContext context)
        {
            Position netdeveloper = new Position() { name = ".net developer", yearsExperienceRequired = 5 };
            Position javadeveloper = new Position() { name = "java developer", yearsExperienceRequired = 5 };

            byte[] johnImage = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\Content\Photos\1.jpg");
            byte[] luisImage = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\Content\Photos\2.jpg");

            Applicant luis = new Applicant()
            {
                name = "Luis",
                skypeuser = "le.valencia",
                telephone = "0491732825",
                photo = luisImage
            };

            Applicant john = new Applicant()
            {
                name = "John",
                skypeuser = "jo.valencia",
                telephone = "3435343543",
                photo = johnImage
            };


            ApplicantPosition appicantposition = new ApplicantPosition()
            {
                Applicant = luis,
                Position = netdeveloper,
                appliedDate = DateTime.Today,
                Status = Status.Applied
            };

            ApplicantPosition appicantposition2 = new ApplicantPosition()
            {
                Applicant = john,
                Position = javadeveloper,
                appliedDate = DateTime.Today,
                Status = Status.Applied
            };

            context.Positions.Add(netdeveloper);
            context.Positions.Add(javadeveloper);
            context.Applicants.Add(luis);
            context.Applicants.Add(john);
            context.ApplicantsPositions.Add(appicantposition);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }




public class HRContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Position> Positions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicantPosition> ApplicantsPositions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationPositionHistory> ApplicationsPositionHistory { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Position>().ToTable("Position");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>().ToTable("Applicant");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicantPosition>().ToTable("ApplicantPosition");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationPositionHistory>().ToTable("ApplicationsPositionHistory");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Position>().Property(c => c.name).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>().Property(c => c.name).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicantPosition>().Property(c => c.appliedDate).IsRequired();

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell EF to use your custom inializer with the [`Database.SetInitializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method. The best to call it at your application start (if you are using MVC then in the Application_Start). But you should only call it once and before you access your context for the first time

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     ...
    Database.SetInitializer(new HRContextInitializer());
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HRContext class you need to set database initializer:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{ 
    Database.SetInitializer(new HTContextInitializer());
}
```